# Multiple Role Database Design

Tags: sql, database, roles, user-roles

I recently had this problem in designing a SQL database.

I want to create a database for a school, and of course not all users have the same role or privileges.

For example, there are teachers, headteacher, students and parents.

If I put all those in the same table and put a role column the table, then I can't be free to put any other columns for a specific role
like I can't add a grade column for student because the other roles don't have grades.

Also I can't put them in separate tables because in the log in I can't specify the role for this user and go to his table .

What is the best way to do something like this?

Comment: You are always make the grade column nullable and let the application deal with nulls however it wants. Polymorphic mapping to same table with a discriminator column which stores the type of the row is one way.

Answer (score 0):

Use polymorphism on the user table.
Create a user table with basic authentication and common information like email and credentials. Now create 2 columns authority_type, authority_id (naming can be changed).

Now for every type of new role or privilege, create a table.
For e.g. In your case, there will be a table for the teacher, headteacher, student and parent. All have separate sets of attributes.

Whenever saving a user record, you'll use its authority_type and its authoriy_id ( record foreign key of that other table ).